# Can I use [Required] and nullable at the same time in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm developing a web application and database using Blazor server-side and Entity Framework Core 6 (with migrations). Currently I'm implementing the model entities and service classes for CRUD operations.

This is an example of a entity-class of an agreement:

```
public class AgreementElement
{
    [Key]
    public int AgreementElementSeq { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }    

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(19,2)")]
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Nullable types are enabled!

Is the way I'm using `[Required]` in addition to nullable types common in EF Core/C#?

The reasons for using this are:

- The field which are nullable (`bool? IsActive`) is assigned default value true when added into the database, thus it should be possible to contain a null value so it doesn't throw an exception when not set when creating AgreementE-object.
- The field with `[Required]` attribute (`string Name`) is NOT nullable in the database. The default value is "" (which I actually don't want to be possible), so maybe it should be nullable as well?
- The fields which are both `[Required]` and nullable:

  1. `[Required]` makes is NOT nullable in database - nice!
  2. If `DateTime` field is not nullable (missing `?` after `DateTime`), it will be set to the default value (DateTime.Min) "01/01/0001" or something like that. That leads to extra if (DateFrom == DateTime.Min) {} inside the CRUDs. Not nice!

When using `DateTime?`, EF Core auto-checks for null and throws exception. Nice! But I need both `[Required]` and `?` after type.

What is the correct way to do this stuff?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: Why do you need the value not to be nullable on DB but to be nullable in Blazor? For example: your bool is supposed to have its default value set to true. So just set it to true when creating the object. Your object is the representation of what you have in the DB, if it is [Required], it should not be nullable. For the DateTime issue, either set the value to a possible one, or use a View Model.

Comment: As above.  Personally I use `DataTime.Min` as a pseudo null and handle it in the UI to display whatever message I want through an extension method on `DateTime`  - normally "Not Set".

Answer (score 0):

Ytou can do something like

```
[Required]  
public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; } = null!;
```

If you are trying to set null on a Required field.

Answer (score 0):

In my side, I try to apply the same logic between persistence data (DB saving in our case) and code. If a property is nullable in DB, I try to set it nullable in C# too.

The other principle I try to follow is business logic first. "Does it make sense that this field is nullable?"

I'd be glad to see other members opinions :)